# Extracting a partial string match up until a specific character within a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I want to extract a string that matches a partial string match from rows of a column until a specific character is met.

I would want all strings from column_3 that start with "String_" until the ";" character.

DF contains something like this:

```
Column_1    column_2    column_3 
A           B           X;A;B;String_123;C
Y           L           Y;Q;S;D;F;String_463;F;L;U
P           Q           K;E;TX;String_103;1;1;D;F
```

All I want are these values:

```
String_123
String_463
String_103
```

Comment: Do `String_...` always happen after 2 `;`?

Comment: No, the number of ";" can vary in each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run:

```
df.column_3.str.extract(r'(?P<Str>String_[^;]+)')
```

*extract* method matches a capturing group.
For identification I gave the name to this group, it will be the name of output column.

The regex used first matches just "String_" and then a non-empty sequence
of chars other than ";".

Answer (score 0):

you can use a regex to extract this info. The regex will match the string "String_" and then 0 or more chars lazily until it sees the first comma

```
data_str = """Column_1    column_2    column_3 
A           B           X;A;B;String_123;C
Y           L           Y;Q;S;D;F;String_463;F;L;U
P           Q           K;E;TX;String_103;1;1;D;F"""

data = [line.split() for line in data_str.splitlines()]
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
print(df['column_3'].str.extract(r'(String_.*?);'))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
            0
0  String_123
1  String_463
2  String_103
```